# Java8 stream operations on nested maps - Map<String, List<Map>>

Tags: java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `Map` of the following kind - `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`. It contains elements in the following format:

```
"1" - [M1, M1, M3]
"2" - [M1, M2, M3]
"3" - [M4]
"4" - [M2, M5]
```

where,

`"1","2","3","4"` are the keys of the outer map of `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`. Let's call them `outerKey`. So, `M1`'s `outerKey`s are `"1", "2"` both. For `M2` it's `"2", "4"`, etc.

`M1, M2, M3, M4, M5` are the internal maps of `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`

The primary key of the distinction between internal maps is `k1` key. (There are other entries also in the internal maps, apart from `k1`). eg:

`M1` - `{ "k1": "m1", "k2": "n1" }`, `M2` - `{ "k1": "m2", "k2": "n2" }`, etc

Now, I want to extract a list of unique internal maps along with it's highest `outerKey`. For eg., for the above-mentioned input, the output should be:

```
M1 - "2"
M2 - "4"
M3 - "2"
M4 - "3"
M5 - "4"
```

The `outerKey` can also be inserted inside the maps so that we can get a list of maps.

So, for the sample input :

```html
    {
     "1": [{
      "k1": "m1",
      "k2": "n1"
     }, {
      "k1": "m1",
      "k2": "n1"
     }, {
      "k1": "m2",
      "k2": "n2"
     }],
     "2": [{
      "k1": "m1",
      "k2": "n1"
     }, {
      "k1": "m2",
      "k2": "n2"
     }, {
      "k1": "m3",
      "k2": "n3"
     }],
     "3": [{
      "k1": "m4",
      "k2": "n4"
     }],
     "4": [{
      "k1": "m2",
      "k2": "n2"
     }, {
      "k1": "m5",
      "k2": "n5"
     }]
    }

Use the following code to convert it into Map:

(JSONObject)JSONValue.parseWithException(data)
```

The output will be :

```html
[{
     "k1": "m1",
     "k2": "n1",
     "outerKey": "2"
    }, {
     "k1": "m2",
     "k2": "n2",
     "outerKey": "4"
    }, {
     "k1": "m3",
     "k2": "n3",
     "outerKey": "2"
    }, {
     "k1": "m4",
     "k2": "n4",
     "outerKey": "3"
    }, {
     "k1": "m5",
     "k2": "n5",
     "outerKey": "4"
    }]
```

I'm having some trouble doing this in java8?

I tried to get a stream of `Map<String, String>` and simultaneously adding the entry(`outerKey`) by doing the following:

```
a.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream(m -> m.put("outerKey",e.getKey())))
```

but it returns a `Stream<String>` because `map.put` returns the previous value associated with the key.

Hence, I couldn't get a `Stream<Map>` with the `entry` added. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Downvoters: seems like it's a very trival problem for you guys. Might not be for others. Maybe that's why I'm asking?

Comment: I haven't read it too carefully, but `m -> { m.put("outerKey",e.getKey(); return m;})` would not work if you want a `Stream<Map...>`?

Comment: `m -> {m.put("outerKey",e.getKey());return m;}` I guess this should work. Why won't it work?

Comment: because at least you would put this entry too many times, you are probably looking for `Collectors.collectingAndThen` here

Comment: By doing what you said, I've gotten the following output:
`{outerKey=1, k1=m1, k2=n1}
{outerKey=1, k1=m1, k2=n1}
{outerKey=1, k1=m2, k2=n2}
{outerKey=2, k1=m1, k2=n1}
{outerKey=2, k1=m2, k2=n2}
{outerKey=2, k1=m3, k2=n3}
{outerKey=3, k1=m4, k2=n4}
{outerKey=4, k1=m2, k2=n2}
{outerKey=4, k1=m5, k2=n5}`. This seems correct to me. Now, I can filter on the basis of `outerKey` and perform desired operation. No?

Comment: I did the following : `a.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(m -> {m.put("outerKey",e.getKey());return m;})).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Is there any `peek` type function where I can interfere with the stream?

Comment: this is a bit unclear, how are computing `outerKey`? Is it always `outerMap#getKey`?

Comment: In this, `"1": [{
        "k1": "m1",
        "k2": "n1"
    }, {
        "k1": "m1",
        "k2": "n1"
    }, {
        "k1": "m2",
        "k2": "n2"
    }]`, for each inner map, the `outerKey` is `1`. Similarly for others.

Comment: yeah because, there is a stream on outer map `a.entrySet().stream()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
a.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(m -> {m.put("outerKey",e.getKey());return m;}))
            .collect(
                groupingBy(m -> m.get("k1"),collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparing(m -> m.get("outerKey"))),o -> ((Optional)o).get())
                )
            )
            .values()
```

Output:

```
[{outerKey=2, k1=m1, k2=n1}, {outerKey=4, k1=m2, k2=n2}, {outerKey=2, k1=m3, k2=n3}, {outerKey=3, k1=m4, k2=n4}, {outerKey=4, k1=m5, k2=n5}]
```